# using esp8266 feather to burn bootloader on redboard

Tags: esp8266, bootloader

Is it possible to burn the bootloader of an arduino redboard using an esp8266 feather? whenever i connect my redboard to my pc the ports list on the ide would just be greyed out. I've looked around online and tried everything I found except burning the bootloader since I didnt have a spare arduino, atmega or a programmer. I have an [EPS8266](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2821) feather though.

If anyone know whether or not this is possible to do and could walk me through on how to do it if it was.

Comment: Sparkfun Redboard? yes it is possible, but complicated and it will not help with port grayed out

Answer (score 1):

The RedBoard has an FT232 chip for the USB interface.  Flashing the bootloader on the main MCU will have no effect at all on your problem.

While, yes, it is technically possible to use the ESP8266, it's not easy and, since it won't cure your problem of a greyed out port option, isn't worth the effort to try and do it.

Instead, you should be looking at things like your USB ports, USB cables, FT232 drivers, etc on your computer.

Comment: well I guess my redboard is broken then. I've tried 3 different cables which I know isn't just for power and the ports work fine with other devices so those are good too, FT232 drivers? don't remember installing those but my arduino worked fine before, and loopback test doesn't work. Guess I need to get a new arduino

Comment: What OS are you using?  Check the chip next to the USB port - it should say "FT232" on it.

Comment: I am on Windows 10. Chip? on my redboard? This is what I see https://imgur.com/a/SQroRKO

Comment: Yep, that's the FT232. The strange looking one.

Comment: the latest project i used on it was this https://i.imgur.com/lyP0gkA.png.
I used an 8pack aa battery for 12v and wired it into the vin to power the arduino. reckon that burned it out?

Comment: You'd need to test the correct functionality of all the components on the board. Start with checking all the right voltages are in the right places.

Comment: It was working as intended. Everything was working fine and the voltages going to the rfid and solenoid was just about right. the voltage going into vin was the exact same as the solenoid at around 11.45v. It's just the next day it just stopped working